# Prestodb cli Oracle Conenction - need help -Error running command: Authentication failed: Unauthorized

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, oracle-sqldeveloper, presto, trino

Can presto installed in one instance query data from Oracle installed in another instance ??

Steps executed

Had Oracle in windows instance .

I have installed Presto in a linux server ,

```
* config.properties :
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8080
query.max-memory=10GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080
```

Created a catalog "oracle.properties " with the valid connection details placed it in : /root/Presto/presto-server-0.245.1/etc/catalog

```
connector.name=oracle
connection-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@3.2.2.2:1521/Databasename
connection-user=Username
connection-password=Passowrd
```

I have placed the cli jar in bin : made it executable chmod +x presto

```
Launched presto : bin/launcher start
```

started at 28562
Use command to run cli :

```
presto --server localhost:8080 --catalog oracle --schema Databasename
```

Cli is started ,

```
presto:Databasename>
```

But when a query is executed it is showing error
Error running command: Authentication failed: Unauthorized
All the details entered in the oracle.properties are valid .
Any suggestion is appreciated , Thanks .

Comment: Troubleshooting of configuration is not the best fit for SO. If you do not get help here, please try the `#troubleshooting` channel on [Presto/Trino community slack](https://trino.io/slack.html).